# Curl: Multiple Cookies

Tags: php, curl

How can I have multiple cookies for each Client/PC to run a script?

If ComputerA run a script then cookies.txt will be created and also ComputerB run same Script then cookies.txt will be over written which is bad.

Example:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're seperate computers, then it's seperate file systems and each will have its own cookie file.

But if you're on shared storage, then use a dynamic filename, perhaps

```
'cookie-' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '.txt'
```

instead, which'd give you

```
cookie-ComputerA.txt    cookie-ComputerB.txt    etc...
```

Comment: I dont think that will work? script will be on the same server but request come from multiple computer.

Comment: Ah. You said "computerA runs a script and computerB runs a script". Two separate computers. In any case, it's still not a problem. The cookie.txt file will be in Netscape cookie file format, which keeps track of which host the cookies came from. Unless you're running the script multiple times in parallel, there's no danger of one cookie overwriting another.

Comment: Marc, Good point but I like to run script on MS-DOS rather than on browser. How can I run the script on MS-DOS (connect to external web)?  On local machine (development) I normally do this: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe index.php` which will execute the code.. Now how can I run this on multiple computer (without LAMP installed)?

Comment: There are PHP compilers which can convert a .php script into a .exe, but they're not guaranteed to work, as PHP cannot be reliably compiled into a .exe. You'd need PHP installed on each machine you want to run the script from.

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the IP that the request comes from and add that to the filename.  This would work unless both computers have the same public IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique identifier to uniquely identify user. User id, session ID or IP address may be a good choice:

```
$user_id = get_user_id_from_somewhere();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie-".$user_id.".txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie-".$user_id.".txt");
```

Comment: Good idea, maybe rand(12345,23423422324) ?

Comment: @user791022 You cannot use random numbers as unique identifier since the PHP's random generator does not guarante collision. If you are using user authentication on your application then you should almost definitely use user ID's for that purpose. Otherwise, I recommend using IP address or hash of IP address (eg. `md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`).