# Run a PHP script from multiple computers?

Tags: php, windows, curl, dos, command-prompt

I have written a PHP Script, I run the code like this on MS-DOS on my local PC:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe index.php
```

Now I want to upload the index.php on the web but on multiple computers (without PHP/Apache installed), how can I run index.php on ms-dos via web?

If that not possible, I can open multiple putty application on each computer and login ssh?

index.php will continues looping - it wont be good to run script on the browser because it may cause timeout via browser.

Comment: Easiest would be via the web.  You can up the timeout for apache.  How long are we talking about?  60 seconds or 10 minutes?

Comment: I think without apache installed, there is no way to access the computer other than by connecting to it using SSH or something similar.

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587847/curl-multiple-cookies

Comment: [HipHop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP) converts PHP code to a standalone program

Comment: Arthur Frankel, For 15 hours a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you're using putty on each computer to log into another machine to run the script, the script will still be running on "the other" machine. All you've done is make its output appear on the local computer that's running putty. It'd be exactly the same as opening multiple shells on the server and running the script in each window.

If you want a PHP script to run "locally", then you need PHP installed locally on each machine that will run the script. And like I said in your other similar question, there are PHP compilers which can produce a .exe that MIGHT be portable, but it's not guaranteed to work. PHP can be compiled, but not all scripts are compileable.

Comment: Marc B, I am have been thinking about this. What I could do, instead running on multiple computers... I could open multiple shells (via putty) on 1 computer and then execute index.php file multiple times. I think that is a best solution, what do you think of that? (In regarding to compiling to EXE, I will look into that - problem is if I need to update PHP code , then I have to update every computer... time consuming).

Comment: You don't need putty to open multiple shells, unless those shells are on another machine... As for the multiple computer .exe, you can always run the .exe off a network drive. Single location for the .exe, but multiple different computers all running the same one.

Comment: I really have two options to look at... I don't want to run code from my local machine. I have a dedicated server from server provider, so shells are necessary?   (second solution... that is a good idea to run the .exe off a network drive)

Answer (score 1):

Check out bamcompile.

It lets you compile the PHP file to an exe.

Not everything works but it is worth the shot: http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/

I think it uses PHP 4.something so don't know wether it works for your script without seeing it

EDIT

You said you are worried about an timeout if ran in browser.

What does the script do?

Perhaps PHP isn't you're best option.

Comment: A script sending information to a company via http using Curl. It will loop for 15 hours a day.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have Apache and PHP installed on those computers, and then have a script visible on that computers that runs the command for you.

```
exec("C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe index.php")
```

This way, you can start running the script without having the script time out from Apache's end.